# how to make audio player like whatsapp in wave surfer in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

how to make audio player like whatsapp in wave surfer in react native

Please provide me any solution , i already search many things , but still i am not to get result , if anyone know any working npm package ,please help me out

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.